# Primes of the form $n^{3} + 2$

Tags: number-theory

Is it known that there are infinitely many primes which can be represented by $n^{3} + 2$ (or similarly any cubic polynomial)?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You might be interested in [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), a generalization of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Comment: It is however known that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^3+2y^3$ (Heath-Brown).

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A144953.

Comment: What's special about $n^3+2$ in particular?

Comment: Presumably it is the ”smallest” cubic without local obstructions ($n^3$ and $n^3 + 1$ are not irreducible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the only single variable polynomials we have a result like this for are linear ones, due to Dirichlet. (Primes in arithmetic progressions).

A lot is known about primes taken by binary (two variable) quadratic forms due to Fermat, Euler, Gauss and many others.

A modern breakthrough proved that there are infinitely many of the form $x^2 + y^4$ (Friedlander–Iwaniec) and $x^3+2y^3$ (Heath-Brown).

As far as I know essentially nothing else is known.

There there should be infinitely many $x^2+1$ is a long standing open problem.

Comment: It just occurred to me that $\binom{n+m+k}{3} +  \binom{n+m}{2} + \binom{m}{1}$ takes on infinitely many primes for the trivial reason that it is a bijection from $\mathbb N^3 \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: Not quite.  $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}=\frac 12(n^2+n)$ misses $4$ among others.  You want $\binom{m+n+1}{2} + \binom{n}{1}$

Comment: and sums of cubes, etc.. by Warings problem.

Comment: @user58512 The reason that Friedlander-Iwaniec and Heath-Brown results are breakthroughs is that the set of integers of those forms is much sparser than any arithmetic progression or even the primes themselves.  In general, $\{\sum_i n_i^{a_i}: n_i \in \mathbb N \}$ is sparse when $c := \sum_i {a_i}^{-1} < 1$, because there are at most $O(x^c)$ such values up to $x$.  That's what makes $x^2+y^4$ exciting and $x^2+13y^2$ less so (not trivial, mind you).

Comment: Dear @ErickWong, isn't the set $\{x^2+y^2 \mid x,y \in \Bbb N\}$ also sparse (i.e. has density $0$) ? Then, in what sense would $p=x^2+13y^2$ be more exciting than $x^2+y^4$ (both sets having density $0$) ?

Comment: @Watson That’s like saying a point and a unit circle both have area $0$ so one can’t be smaller than the other.  We can quantify density much more finely than just “$0$” by considering the asymptotic behavior of the counting function.  More to the point, the set $\{x^2+y^2\}$ is unboundedly *denser* than the primes and it even has positive density within the primes.  The set $\{x^2+y^4\}$ has density zero with respect to the primes even before taking intersections.  As I alluded above, the counting function is only $O(x^{3/4})$ vs the primes’ $O(x/\ln x)$.